# avoid mismatched tags outputting HTML with XSLT

Tags: xslt

I'm new to XSLT, and there's one specific thing I don't know how to do, despite hours of searching for the answer.

I'm outputting blocks of HTML (result sets), and sometimes the result is a hyperlink, sometimes it is not.

The simple flow looks like this:

```
<a...> if @url

some HTML code

</a> if @url
```

But if I do:

```
when @url
<a...>
/when

some HTML code

when @url
</a>
/when
```

... I'm told that I have mismatched tags.

I was using CDATA text for the anchor set, but a lot of messages say that this is a "hack" approach.

I'm trying to avoid having to repeat the entire HTML code block only to include the anchors on only one of them.

How do I do this?

-------edit / additional info-----------

Does this make more sense?

```
            <xsl:template match="Row">

                            <xsl:choose>
                            <xsl:when test="@url!=''">
                                    <a><xsl:attribute name="href"><xsl:value-of select="@url" /></xsl:attribute>
                            </xsl:when>
                            </xsl:choose>       

                                    <img />

                            <xsl:choose>
                            <xsl:when test="@url!=''">
                                    </a>
                            </xsl:when>
                            </xsl:choose>       

            </xsl:template>
```

Comment: Please post your _actual_ XSLT. What you posted doesn't make any sense.

Comment: I've amended the original post.  Hopefully that helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In XSLT, your output is a tree of nodes. Writing an element node is a single atomic operation; it can't be split into separate operations of writing a start tag and writing an end tag. You can't create half a node.

If you do try to treat `<a>` and `</a>` as separate and separable operations, you will get this error, because the stylesheet must be well-formed XML.

So, stand back and explain what you are trying to achieve, and then we can tell you how to achieve it properly in XSLT.

Comment: Your sentence "In XSLT, your output is a tree of nodes." set me on the right path.  I had learned the insides of XSLT but had missed the bigger picture.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

One way to refactor the XSLT to conditionally apply the hyperlink and not repeat the logic to produce the `<img/>` (or whatever more complex logic you are trying to avoid repeating) is to **extract that logic out into a different template(s) as either a named template or a template with a `@mode`**.

For instance:

```
  <xsl:template match="Row">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="@url!=''">

          <a>
            <xsl:attribute name="href">
                <xsl:value-of select="@url"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="image"/>
          </a>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="image"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
   </xsl:choose>             
  </xsl:template>

    <!--The "common" logic to produce an image element, whether or not it will be surrounded by an anchor linking to the @url -->
<xsl:template match="Row" mode="image">
    <img/>
</xsl:template>
```

An alternative way of accomplishing the same thing, but using templates instead of `<xsl:choose>`:

```
  <xsl:template match="Row[@url]">
    <a href="@url">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="image"/>
    </a>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Row">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="image"/>            
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Row" mode="image">
        <img/>
  </xsl:template>
```